# Why won't the instance variables change?

Tags: java, logic, class-variables

```
class CoinExchanger {

    private int rs5, rs2, rs1;

    public boolean canDispenseCoins(int amount){
        return (amount<( rs5*5 + rs2*2 + rs1))? true: false;
    }

    public void dispenseCoins(int amount){
         int qt = amount/5;
         rs5 = (qt>rs5)?0: rs5-qt ;

         qt = (amount%5) / 2;
         rs2 = (qt>rs2)?qt-rs2: rs2-qt ;

         qt = ((amount%5) / 2)/1;
         rs1 = (qt>rs1)?qt-rs1: rs1-qt ;

        out.printf("5Rs coins : %d, 2Rs coins : %d, 1Rs coins : "
                + "%d\n", rs5, rs2, rs1);

    }
}
```

This is the coin dispenser. It asks the user to enter three integers and amount of coins to be dispensed...

Here I input `rs5 = 10`, `rs2 = 10`, `rs1 = 10` and `amount = 56`. After dispensing the amount of coins, there should be `rs5 = 0`, `rs2 = 7`, and `rs1 = 10`. But the above code didn't show the right answer. All it shows it's right is `rs5 = 0` and the others are `10`. So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: So what diagnostic steps did you take to solve the problem? Have you stepped through it in a debugger, observing `qt` at every step?

Comment: What is the value of 56 % 5? What is the value of (56 % 5) / 2?

Comment: I want the remainder of each of the integers to check if 56 coins are all dispensed...

Answer (score 0):

You are using :

```
qt = ((amount%5) / 2)/1;
```

Instead of :

```
qt = ((amount%5) % 2)/1;
```

With that you get result as:

5Rs coins : 0, 2Rs coins : 10, 1Rs coins : 9

(5*10)+(1*1)= 56

Another thing, you could just as easily use your function dispenseCoins and return boolean for dispensable when amount of coins is enough && matches whole amount.